# Gitlab CI/CD running Unit tests

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

I need to run unit tests on gitlab pipeline.
Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
image: napp/php-ci:7.4-fpm

services:
  - name: mysql:5.7
    alias: mysql

variables:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass_root
  MYSQL_DATABASE: db_test
  MYSQL_USER: user
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
  DATABASE_URL: 'mysql://user:test@mysql:3306/db_test'

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
    - staging
  services:
    - mysql:5.7
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install zip unzip
    - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
    - php composer-setup.php
    - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
    - php composer.phar install
    - php bin/console app:deploy:symfony:local
    - ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

On gitlab I have error: `Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'db_test_test'`
Why it does not make tests on `db_test` but on 'db_test_test'`?

Can you please help me so I could run it appropriate db - `db_test`

Answer (score 0):

Check your env.test file or any other environment file that you are using for testing. There will be a line which adds a prefix `_test` to your database name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying. Here's my env file for testing:
`
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st'
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=999999
PANTHER_APP_ENV=panther
APP_ENV=test
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:test@mysql:3306/db_test
MAILER_DSN=null://null #Keep like this
`

Comment: @OleksiiZakharuk you should have .env.test file.